# How to use JS classes (or similar concept) within AlpineJS modules

Tags: javascript, class, module, singleton, alpine.js

I use the following Todo module with AlpineJS in order to have a central logic/schema for data handling. It works in general. However, when I add multiple entries, they all point to the same instance; so when I add a new to do, all the todo's in the list adapt the new name.

To avoid this I tried using a class instead of just a module, however, this does not seem to work at all with AlpineJS.

Any idea how to best tackle this approach?

**Notes Using Class Export:**

1. The error I get when trying to use a class is: *Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor default cannot be invoked without 'new'*
2. I tried `x-data="new todo()"`. Then I get the error: *todo is not a constructor*
3. I also tried `Alpine.data('todo', new Todo());`. Then I get the error: *Uncaught TypeError: callback.bind is not a function*

**Notes Using Function Export:**

1. It works with multiple (different) entries, when I just push `item.name` into the list, instead of (the whole) `item`, probably because it gets converted to a simple string, but I need the whole object unfortunatetly.
2. When I tried to use `todos.push(structuredClone(item))` I got the error: *Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'structuredClone' on 'Window': # could not be cloned.*

```js
// <todo.js>
/* CLASS EXPORT: Does not work at all */
export default class {
    constructor(name, completed = false){
        this.item = {
          name: name,
          completed: completed
        }
    }
};

/* FUNCTION EXPORT: Works, but all items point to the same instance */
export default() => ({
    item: {
      name: '',
      completed: false
    }

});
```

```html
<script type="module">
  import Alpine from './modules/alpine.js';
  import Todo from './modules/todo.js';

  Alpine.data('todo', Todo);
  Alpine.start();
</script>
 <article x-data="{ todos: [] }">

        <form x-data="todo" @submit.prevent="todos.push(item)">
            <input x-model="item.name"><button>Add</button>
        </form>

       <ul>
            <template x-for="todo in todos">
                <li x-text="todo.name"></li>
            </template>
       </ul>
    </article>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `todo.js` you can first create the `Todo` class, then export it:

```
class Todo {
    constructor(name, completed = false) {
        this.name = name
        this.completed = completed
    }
}

export default Todo
```

Note that I removed `item` property from the `Todo` class.

In the HTML file you also need to set Todo as a global class (`window.Todo`). You need to remove the `Alpine.data('todo', Todo)` and `x-data="todo"` parts since `Todo` is not an Alpine.js component, so don't try to use it as one. I also created a new property `new_todo_name` that holds the new todo's label until it is created with `todos.push(new Todo(new_todo_name))`.

```
<script type="module">
  import Alpine from './modules/alpine.js'
  import Todo from './modules/todo.js'
  window.Todo = Todo

  Alpine.start()
</script>
<article x-data="{ todos: [], new_todo_name: '' }">
  <form @submit.prevent="todos.push(new Todo(new_todo_name)); new_todo_name = ''">
    <input x-model="new_todo_name"><button>Add</button>
  </form>

  <ul>
     <template x-for="todo in todos">
       <li x-text="todo.name"></li>
     </template>
  </ul>
</article>
```

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I tried to do.